# show max, min and current value on website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I would like to show current price of something compared to its historic maximum and minimum. Something like this:
[image]
I mean that bar between max and min. I thought I could tweak [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) by disabling it. But I want something smaller (width like 100px) and disabled slider is not what I want exactly.
My question is, **what is the best (preferably bootstrap) way to show max-min along with current value**?

Comment: Perhaps a simple table with three columns and in the second column a progress bar? See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: thanks, since there are no other suggestion, I will probably and up using progess bar.